# Shorthand to Init a Scala Enumeration ValueSet with one Value

Tags: scala

So I have a some Scala Enumeration object:

```
object KnotType extends Enumeration {
        type KnotType = Value
    val STOPPER, HITCH, ENDLOOP, MIDLOOP, ADJUSTABLELOOP, BEND, BINDING = Value
  }
  import KnotType._

  object AnotherType extends Enumeration {
        ...      }
  import AnotherType ._
```

I want to initialize a new ValueSet instance with one Value present only. In the shortest of shorthands:

```
val eKnots = STOPPER + HITCH
eKnot: KnotType.ValueSet = KnotType.ValueSet(STOPPER , HITCH)
```

Works a charm. However, to create a ValueSet from one value I have to be more explicit: (especially as there are more than on enum object classes)

Creating a enumeration from one value produces a Value (as expected) but is not what I'm after (a ValueSet):

```
val eKnot = STOPPER
eKnot: KnotType.Value = STOPPER
```

A conventional way would be:

```
val eKnot =  KnotType.ValueSet(STOPPER)
eKnot: KnotType.ValueSet = KnotType.ValueSet(STOPPER)
```

an inelegant way:

```
val eKnot = STOPPER + STOPPER
eKnot: KnotType.ValueSet = KnotType.ValueSet(STOPPER)
```

a long winded way - works fine but I'm after succinctness

```
val eKnot = KnotType.ValueSet.empty + STOPPER
eKnot: KnotType.ValueSet = KnotType.ValueSet(STOPPER)
```

Is there any other shorthand I could use?
i.e 
val eKnot = STOPPER + /somethingsimple/

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own extension method (similar to JavaConverters):

```
implicit class ValueToValueSet(v: Value) {
  def toSet: ValueSet = ValueSet(v)
}

val eKnot: KnotType.ValueSet = STOPPER.toSet
```

Or implicit conversion (not recommended I think as this is similar to JavaConversions):

```
implicit def valueToValueSet(v: Value): ValueSet = ValueSet(v)

val eKnot: KnotType.ValueSet = STOPPER
```

Comment: The second option is exactly the thing I was looking for. There is a typo though. ValueSet(x) should read ValueSet(v). Thanks